# Network Shares with WIndows 2008 and UAC

Tags: networking, uac

I am trying to create a network share during an install on Window Server 2008 and I have been running into UAC problems. It seems that even though I am running as administrator during the installation process the batch file run by the installer can not create the share. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: This may be better suited to http://serverfault.com.

Comment: But because it's batch and batch is technically programming, I'm not going to vote to close.

Comment: I'm just sayin; you may get a better response there.

Comment: serverfault.com is in beta and I don't have access

Comment: If you're using any code, it would be helpful to include it here. i can create shares fine. If you're getting an error message, it would be useful to include it here.